# Word too long for radio button

Tags: html, radio-button, translation

I've got a page that we're translating into German on the fly. On the page is a set of three radio buttons, arranged horizontally. In English they're displayed fine, but in German the label text gets layered over top of the button/label to the right. Since the text is only one (long!) word in German, wrapping doesn't kick in. Any suggestions for a fix that won't affect the English language presentation (ie. really large margins that will look bad when the English text wraps)? Screenshot below:

[screenshot of problem http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2604/germantext.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2604/germantext.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the CSS `word-wrap` property to `break-word` for the radio button?

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I need, and I can just add it to the existing class specification. I really should look at the CSS3 stuff I guess :)

Comment: The declaration `word-wrap: break-word` really breaks words: it brutally breaks a string at arbitrary points. This is definitely incorrect for German and most other languages. It is just as incorrect as it is to break the English word “right” to “ri” and “ght” (without inserting a hyphen).

Comment: I agree it's not the perfect solution, but at this point it's looking the the only usable solution (for us). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [soft hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) (`&shy;`). It will allow line breaking, displaying a hyphen; but it is not shown otherwise. Your CSS obviously allows line wrapping (as seen in other labels) - let it work for you. E.g.

```
Super&shy;cali&shy;fragi&shy;listic&shy;expi&shy;ali&shy;docious
```

will be able to be rendered like

```
Supercalifragilistic-
expialidocious
```

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for future projects, but it won't work in this case. As I mentioned, we're doing the translation on the fly. I have no idea what the word will be in German, and I have no ability to go in and add code to split it up.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to put alternative (radio button and its label) on a line of its own. This is good for usability and accessibility, and it solves the problem at hand en passant. Save trouble, not space.

If that’s not regarded as feasible, apply the approach suggested by Amadan, but dynamically. There are various ways of inserting soft hyphens on the fly, server-side or client-side. Check out a [demo of client-side hyphenation](http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/code/javascript/hyphenation.html), which works even for mixed-language content (vary the browser window width to see the effect). The demo uses [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).

Comment: Yeah, vertical vs horizontal is much better, but I don't have any control over the layout. I'll take a deeper look at Hyphenator.js, but at a glance it doesn't support all the languages we need out of the box and adding all the patterns would be time-prohibitive. Thanks.

Comment: @shimmoril, handling most languages right (with hyphenation) is still better than handling all languages in a seriously broken way (break words).

Comment: I'd agree with you if it was actually _most_ languages. Of the languages likely to have this issue (ie. significantly long single words) that we make available to our users, Hyphenator.js supports exactly one - German. That leaves 6-7 languages without any solution at all. And when the text overruns the field size like that, it's basically unreadable and therefore unusable. I'm going to keep Hyphenator in mind for future implementation, but for right now the word-wrap fix is the only workable solution for our product.